# Mod_Evasive for IIS 7

Tags: .net, iis

I think my comany's IIS website might be under DoS attack. I know mod_evesive in apache but don't know anything related to IIS7.

I'd appreciate If someone could  tell me what is the equivalent for mod_evasive in IIS 7 ? Or If there is anything alse I should be looking for.

Thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Dynamic IP Restrictions](http://www.iis.net/download/DynamicIPRestrictions), a free IIS 7 plugin from Microsoft.

Comment: This IIS module is good. "Dynamic IP Restrictions"